# Slicer selection based on Range

Tags: slicers

I have a Pivot Table showing a list of customers meeting a specific criteria. 
Further I have a string of other Pivot Tables connected to a slicer. 
I need my slicer to automatically filter for the customer codes appearing on the first pivot table.

I have the below - However I am getting 'Error 457 - The Key is already associated with an element in this collection'
What is going wrong?

```
Option Explicit

Sub filterSlicers()

    Dim i As Long, SI As SlicerItem, SC As SlicerCache, PvT As PivotTable, C As Range, Cell As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim DictFilter As Scripting.Dictionary

    For Each PvT In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables
        PvT.ManualUpdate = True
    Next PvT

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set C = ws.Range("A12:A120")

    Set DictFilter = New Scripting.Dictionary
    For Each Cell In C
        DictFilter.Add Cell.Value, 1
    Next Cell


    Set SC = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Customer_Code")
    SC.ClearAllFilters
    For Each SI In SC.VisibleSlicerItems
        Set SI = SC.SlicerItems(SI.Name)
        If DictFilter.Exists(SI.Name) Then
            SI.Selected = True
        Else
            SI.Selected = False
        End If
    Next

    For Each PvT In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables
        PvT.ManualUpdate = False
    Next PvT
End Sub
```

Thank you,